# Codechef beginner permut2: getting error -it gives wrong answer on codechef but gives correct for sample input

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Question**:

A permutation of the integers 1 to n is an ordering of these integers. So the natural way to represent a permutation is to list the integers in this order. With n = 5, a permutation might look like 2, 3, 4, 5, 1. 
However, there is another possibility of representing a permutation: You create a list of numbers where the i-th number is the position of the integer i in the permutation. Let us call this second possibility an inverse permutation. The inverse permutation for the sequence above is 5, 1, 2, 3, 4. 
An ambiguous permutation is a permutation which cannot be distinguished from its inverse permutation. The permutation 1, 4, 3, 2 for example is ambiguous, because its inverse permutation is the same. To get rid of such annoying sample test cases, you have to write a program which detects if a given permutation is ambiguous or not.

**Input Specification**

The input contains several test cases. 
The first line of each test case contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100000). Then a permutation of the integers 1 to n follows in the next line. There is exactly one space character between consecutive integers. You can assume that every integer between 1 and n appears exactly once in the permutation. 
The last test case is followed by a zero.

**Output Specification**

For each test case output whether the permutation is ambiguous or not. Adhere to the format shown in the sample output.

**Sample Input**

```
4
1 4 3 2
5
2 3 4 5 1
1
1
0
```

**Answer**:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int t;
while(true){

    scanf("%d",&t); // no of digits/numbers
    if(t ==0)            //if its 0 then break
        break;  
    int a[t+2],i=1;
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&a[i++]);       // take t numbers
    }

    int f=0;
    for(int j=1;j<i;j++){       
        int p=a[j];     //for every position take array value at that position
        f=0;
        if(a[p]!= j){    //for array value at that position check if its equal to index according to sample input or output

            f=1;         // if fails for any digit then break loop and not ambiguous
            break;
        }       
    }

    if(f==1)
        printf("not ambiguous\n"); //inverse ambiguous
    else
        printf("ambiguous\n");    //not ambiguous
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with your code? Doesn't it compile? (If so, what compiler errors and warnings did you get, and on which lines)? Does it produce the wrong results? (If so: on what inputs)? Is it too slow? (If so: on what inputs)? What have you done to debug it? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/ describes how to ask a good question when your code isn't working.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question, but your code is a mix of C and C++ and while your program may work, it's best to pick and learn one or the other and not mix and match. Variable length arrays `int a[t+2]` are in modern C, but not C++. `printf` and `scanf` are C (although they work but are discouraged in C++) and `cout<<` and `use namespace` are both C++ only.

Comment: it works just fine on my compiler.but gives wrong answer on codechef platform.there is no compile or run time error.i have edited the post.

Comment: What compiler do you use that this works fine on? When I try to compile it I get errors about `scanf` and `printf` not being declared.

Comment: i am using (MinGW)gcc 5.3.0 gnu's compiler

Comment: And how do you compile your code? Do you get any warnings?

Comment: compile: g++ prognamename.cpp for run:a in windows

Comment: Are you sure the program you're compiling is exactly the same as the one you have pasted into the question?

Comment: yes sure it also compiles on codechef platform just gives wrong answer

Comment: I tried your code on codechef and got the same errors as I did when I compiled it on my machine: errors that `scanf` and `printf` aren't defined. If I fixed those it was submitted successfully, and passed the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you couldn't create such a large (100000 elements) arrays inside function. You should create one global array:

```
using namespace std;

const int MaxN = 100000;
int a[MaxN+2];

int main(){
...
}
```